# Appendices showing with .1 in document

Tags: appendices, thesis, article

I am writing a thesis, with articles directly put in it. They contain appendices, which are not the appendix of the thesis itself. In the thesis, the appendices of the articles appear with ".1" and not "A" or "B" as in the original article (what I want). How can I do that ?

**Edit 1:**
At the end of a chapter, I put:

```
\begin{appendices}
\section{Title}
\end{appendices}
```

It displays:

```
.1 Title
```

And I would like something like:

```
A Title
```

or

```
1 Title
```

but not ".1" with a dot in front.

**Edit 2:** If I put "chapter{Title}" instead, I obtain:

```
Appendix A
Title
```

And it is too big (because of "chapter").

Comment: Can you make a complete, minimal example? It would be much easier to give good advice if we know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: That's hardly a complete example (see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)), but what happens if you do `\chapter{Title}` instead of `\section{Title}` in the appendices?

Comment: I edited my question. If I use chapter the titles are too big.

Comment: But you'll have multiple sections A ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}}
```

but this will produce multiples sections with number A.

---

A workaround

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\edef\TheChapter{\thechapter}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand\thesection{\TheChapter.\Alph{section}}}
```

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\edef\TheChapter{\thechapter}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand\thesection{\TheChapter.\Alph{section}}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\begin{appendices}
\section{Title}
\end{appendices}
\blinddocument
\begin{appendices}
\section{Title}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly in the chapter, but in the "Contents", the appendices are numbered with .1, .2, etc...

Comment: for `toc` always you need to compile twice.

Comment: Ok, it is perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution to this may be the subappendices-environment:

```
\begin{subappendices}
```

In my case, hyperlinks to the appendix sections were not correct anymore, when I used the code suggested by touhami.

If you want to keep "Appendix A", instead of "Appendix 1.A" you could additionally use:

```
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

Comment: What package provides the `subappendices` environment?